# How update an array in a map using arrayUnion?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, I have a document containing a map called `myMap`, which contains an array field called `myArr`.

Is it possible to use `arrayUnion` to update `myArr`, by adding an element to it, within a transaction?

```
await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction: Transaction) => {
    //

    const docRef: DocumentReference = admin.firestore()
        .doc(`collection/document`);

    const doc: DocumentSnapshot = await transaction.get(docRef);

    if (doc.exists) 
        await transaction.update(docRef,
            {'myMap': {'myArr': FieldValue.arrayUnion('myNewValue')},}
        );

});
```

I believe the above code should add `myArr`, but it's instead replacing the entire array.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FieldValue.arrayUnion()` and `FieldValue.arrayRemove()` only work when the field identified in the top level of the update object is itself a list.  What you're doing now by providing an object with a list is indeed replacing the entire list.  It won't recognize the existing contents of that list.

What you can do instead is call out the specific name of the embedded list:

```
    await transaction.update(docRef,
        {'myMap.myArr': FieldValue.arrayUnion('myNewValue')},}
    );
```

Note the dot notation for calling out the list specifically.

Comment: How to do it if I want to replace .myArr with a variabel to do the update dynamically ? 
I tried `myMap.${myVar}` but it doesnt work.